# Uwsgi fails with: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding

Tags: python, django, uwsgi

I have configured uWSGI with NGIX and django.

Uwsgi fails with message:

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named encodings
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found problem. I have installed uwsgi plugins both for python and python3. Python3 plugin was used, while default interpreter for my system was python 2.6.

When I uninstalled uwsgi python3 plugin problem dissapeared. You can also specify what plugin to use for speciffic application by setting the `plugins` option.

Comment: Hi JB, can you please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16272542/uwsgi-fails-with-no-module-named-encoding-error I am getting the same error but not sure how to resolve it. Can you tell what exactly you did in your case